# Run SefAutil.exe for multiple users and get one File

Tags: powershell, skype-for-business

I am trying to create a script to run daily to get the list of users
delegates information, but `SefAutil` can't accept piping.

Currently, I assign the result to `$result` for the first user, then export to a text file, and `$result2` for the second user, and so on, but I have 20 users, which means 20 text files.

Not sure how to create it so that all output goes to the
same text or CSV file with all the users' info. 
Is this possible?

```
$result = .\SEFAUtil.exe sip:username.com /server:SFB FDN |  Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\EA\Whatever.TXT
$result1 = .\SEFAUtil.exe sip:jusername.com /server:SFB FDN  |  Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\EA\whatever2.TXT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following processes multiple users and sends the combined output to a single text file:

```
$users = 'username1.com', 'username2.com' # ...

$users | foreach { .\SEFAUtil.exe sip:$_ /server:SFB FDN } > C:\temp\Whatever.TXT
```

`foreach` is an alias for the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet, which processes input objects one by one, with the input object at hand reflected in automatic variable `$_`.

Note: `>` is (effectively) an alias of `Out-File`.